# Find nodes in directed graph that is reachable from all other nodes

Tags: algorithm, graph, directed-graph

**Questions:**

Given a directed graph of N nodes and M edges (M <= 2.N). Find all the nodes that is reachable from all other nodes.

**Example:**

The below graph has 4 nodes and 4 edges:

[image]

**Answer:** Node *(2)* and *(3)* is reachable from all other nodes.

**P/S:**

The only solution I came up with is to revert the graph, BFS all nodes and check if they reach all other nodes. But it would take O(n^2).

Is there any other approach that takes O(n.logn) or less?

Here's my take on the O(n^2) approach:

```
void init(){
    cin >> n >> m;
    for(int i = 0; i < m; i++){
        int u, v; cin >> u >> v;
        adj[v].emplace_back(u);
    }
}

void dfs(int u){
    visited[u] = true;
    for(int v : adj[u])
        if(!visited[v]) dfs(v);
}

init();
for(int u = 1; u <= n; u++){
    memset(visited, 0, sizeof visited);
    dfs(u);
    if(count(visited + 1, visited + n + 1, 1) == n) cout << u << ' ';
}
```

Comment: What data structure are you using to store the edges? Given that there may be O(N^2) edges, the problem gets easier if you can also test for existence of edges in O(1) time. However, your runtime requirement of strictly below O(N^2) rules out running a standard BFS or DFS even once.

Comment: @kcsquared M is <= 2.N (i just added), so a standard BFS or DFS only takes O(n)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get an O(|V| + |E|) algorithm using [Tarjan's strongly connected components algorithm.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_strongly_connected_components_algorithm) Many [sample implementations are available online](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Tarjan) or in standard algorithms textbooks.

Once you have the strongly connected components, the set of vertices reachable from all others is exactly the set of vertices whose strongly connected component(s) have out-degree 0 (the sinks in the graph). However, there is one exception: if the condensation of the graph (the new graph induced by the strongly connected components) is not connected, there are no such vertices. You can test the connectivity of a directed acyclic graph in O(|V|) time, by running a breadth-first search from any in-degree 0 vertex.

Answer (score 1):

Can You share that code which take `O(n^2)` ?

Anyway, This approach only take O(n), Which is better then O(n log n)!

```js
class DirectedGraph {
    graph = {}
    constructor(directedGraph) {
        for (let [id, arrow] of directedGraph)
            this.graph[id] = { arrow, isVisited: false }
    }
    find_end_points(id) {
        let out = [], graph = this.graph;
        function go_next(id, from) {
            let node = graph[id];
            if (node.isVisited || !node.arrow) return out.push(id)
            if (node.arrow == from) out.push(id);
            node.isVisited = true;
            go_next(node.arrow, id);
        }
        go_next(id, null);
        return out
    }
}
let directedGraph = new DirectedGraph([[2, 3], [3, 2], [1, 2], [4, 1]]);
console.log(directedGraph.find_end_points(4))
```

Comment: i can't quite understand how the code work, can you explain it a little bit or provide a pseudo code?

Comment: i have updated my O(n^2) code

Comment: the code doesn't work when i updated the third edge from [1, 2] to [1, 4]. Can you check it?

Comment: @UTL, Can you provide full list?

Comment: @unglinh279, Which part  you didn't understand ?

Comment: @Nur like UTL said, if the edges are: [2, 3], [3, 2], [1, 4], [4, 1], the code returns [2, 3], which is not the right answer

Comment: Indeed, the answer is right, if you start from node 2 or 3 then It would yield  `[2, 3]`, And if you start from node 4 or 1, then  the result would be  `[1, 4]`

Comment: @unglinh279, If the input is `[[2, 3], [3, 2], [1, 4], [4, 1]]`  and you start from 2 or 3, what output you expect ?

Comment: @Nur with that input, nodes 2 and 3 is not reachable from 1 and 4 and vice versa. Hence the answer should be none

Comment: And it can't be done, without knowing where that node coming from, So for  that you need to check all node that so was connected via a single string,